# How should I use deferLater within a for loop

Tags: twisted

It doesn't necessarily have to be within a for loop, but how would you process data a list of data putting twisted's asynchronous "sleep" in the middle. Essentially, I would like to accomplish something like this, which obviously doesn't work. It runs right through the loop with no sleep. Does deferLater need to be used on a method only? If so, how would I essentially achieve the same results using twisted so there is a "sleep" between every DB save entry?

```
 @defer.inlineCallbacks
 def queryDatabase(self, kwargs):

    #Just testing deferLater
    for x in xrange(10000):
        yield txmongo.my_db.test_collection.save({"something":x * time.time()},safe=True)
        d = deferLater(reactor, 5, lambda: none)
        print str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ' ==> ' + str(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never fails, just need to write down the problem, and I come across the answer. This seems to work for me:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def query(self, kwargs):

    # insert some test data
    for x in xrange(10000):
        print str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '===>' + str(x)
        yield deferLater(reactor, 5, lambda: none)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def makeRequest(self, kwargs):
    g = yield self.query(kwargs)
```